# spring security css styles don't work

Tags: css, security, spring, filter

I have a problem applying css to the web pages, using spring security (3.0.7 version). I have the following config:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/faces/resources/**" filters="none"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/faces/inicio.xhtml" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/faces/paginas/autenticacion/login.xhtml*" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/faces/paginas/administracion/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/faces/paginas/barco/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/faces/paginas/catalogo/**" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/faces/paginas/error/**" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/faces/paginas/plantillas/**" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
```

By default, I deny access to the whole pages. Then, I apply authorization to the concrete pages specifying their URLs patterns, and they apply first in the given order, being the denyAll rule the last one.

- "inicio.xhtml" is the homepage.
- "login.xhtml" is the login form.
- "administracion" and "barco" directories contain pages that should be accessed just by authenticated users.
- "catalogo" directory contains pages that should be accessed by everyone.
- "error" directory contains the error pages of the app.
- "plantillas" directory contains the template facelets pages of the
  app (I use JSF2).

The "resources" directory contain images, css files, and javascript. So in the first line I tell spring security not to use the security filter for it.

However, with this configuration, when I run the app, css styles are not applied to pages!!

I've checked that if I turn the default authorization to "permitAll", it works. But I don't want to do that, beacuse it isn't a good practice.

Any idea why not working? I think it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works if you are adding stylesheets inline. For example:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/style.css" />
```

If you are using

```
<h:outputStylesheet>
```

tag, the url pattern should be like this

```
<intercept-url pattern="/faces/javax.faces.resource/**" filters="none"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Ravi, I added '<intercept-url pattern="/faces/javax.faces.resource/**" filters="none"/>' and css works. It took me lot of time to make the favicon work though. Finally I solved it this way: '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#{request.contextPath}/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />' in the page and adding the rule: '<intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" filters="none"/>'

Comment: just create resources/images and put your favicon.ico there and use this in your xhtml <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#{resource['images:favicon.ico']}" type="image/x-icon" />...this way you do not have to create a separate intercept-url for icon ( javax.faces.resource will take care of it).